# RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMq instance running on my local computer and am trying to connect to it from a containerized application ( docker).

I am getting the following error:

RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable.

Inner exceptions:

```
Inner Exception 1:
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)

Inner Exception 2:
ConnectFailureException: Connection failed

Inner Exception 3:
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

My code runs perfectly outside of the container.

here's my client code:

```
 bool IsRunningInContainer = bool.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER"), out var inDocker) && inDocker;
       var host = IsRunningInContainer ? "EarthSimulator" : this._appSettings.Value.MessageQueueHostName;
       var factory = new ConnectionFactory
           {
               HostName = host,
               UserName = this._appSettings.Value.MessageQueueUserName,
               Password = this._appSettings.Value.MessageQueuePassword
           };
      
           this._connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

Here's my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RabbitMq.Web.Client/RabbitMq.Web.Client.csproj", "RabbitMq.Web.Client/"]
COPY ["HangFire.Domain/RabbitMq.Client.Domain.csproj", "HangFire.Domain/"]
COPY ["HangFire.Infrastructure/RabbitMq.Client.Infrastructure.csproj", "HangFire.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["HangFire.Application/RabbitMq.Client.Application.csproj", "HangFire.Application/"]
RUN dotnet restore "RabbitMq.Web.Client/RabbitMq.Web.Client.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/RabbitMq.Web.Client"
RUN dotnet build "RabbitMq.Web.Client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RabbitMq.Web.Client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RabbitMq.Web.Client.dll"]
```

Thanks for any insight about what I am getting wrong

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem turned out to be: Use "host.docker.internal" as hostname and authenticate with a user other than "guest"